# using node module in cordova

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, npm

I am working on a node module I'd like to use in Cordova. 
I am using the syntax

```
 myModule.prototype.myMethod = function(){};
 module.exports = new myModule();
```

but I am getting a "module is not defined" error.

Comment: try `module.exports.myModule= myModule`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined'){
    module.exports = new myModule();
} else{
    window.myModule = new myModule();
}
```